# Crawling Twitter using multiple keywords

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

We have some quick question about putting together a web crawler to collect some data from Twitter.

For example, if we want to use a few hundreds of `user IDs` as keywords to collect some necessary Tweets. However, it seems we can only use a limited number of keywords (12?) and we can launch one crawler at one time.

Any tips?

Comment: Why can't you launch more than one crawler at a time? Where is the keyword limit?

Comment: What have you done till now, could you share your current code..? It would be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve here if users saw your code. Also could you add the links to the API docs to which you have made references to?

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Twitter API restrictions (rate limiting)](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1) it is not imaginable to crawl the whole website, unless you have a lot of time or unless you pay in order to have a special access to the twitterhose, which should be the only way to solve the problem you mentioned